# ASP.NET MVC / C# : how to display partial view data that belongs to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, partial-views

I have this view called BlogsCategory.cshtml that belongs to CategoryController. Currently on this view the page loads a list of my Blog Categories the way its supposed to.

In addition to that data loading already I want to be able to also load data on that same view(BlogsCategory.cshtml) that belongs to another Controller called AdvertisementController whos data comes from another table called tblAdvertisement.

I did not want to create a database relationship between the BlogCategories Table and the Advertisement Table so I was wondering how in the world can I accomplish this via partial views that can load data from AdvertisementController on a view that belongs to CategoryController.

I have tried to add this @Html.Partial on that view but keep getting an error that states that the error below.

```
@model List<Systex.Models.tblCategory>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Advertisement/Horizontal1.cshtml")
```

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Systex.Models.tblBlogsCategory]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Systex.Models.tblAdvertisement'.'

Then the view that holds the piece of data that I want to load looks like this. This is a view of the AdvertisemenController that I am trying to call from the BlogsCategory.cshtml view.

Horizontal1.cshtml

```
@model Systex.Models.tblAdvertisement

//Display these 2 strings on the view called BlogsCategory.cshtml
@Model.BlogCategoriesListVerticalString1
@Model.BlogCategoriesListVerticalString2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to create a DB relationship, which if you are using EFCore I would recommend, then you will have to pass some identifying information to the controller such as an ID and look up the data then to map to the view model.

Comment: Right on man, thanks! It worked, I kind of did what you suggested except instead of using id's I just used viewbags. In the controller I created an instance of the table where the data is, then assigned each field from the table as a value for each of the viewbags and then, on the view I loaded up the ViewBags and got them to display the data.